# C# Game Server Tick

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, server, action

I have a C# game server, where i have an object for each match. Each match has 2 players, and i'm trying to find a way to handle a "server tick" in each match. I've tough about two ways that i can achieve this, but i don't think any of the 2 ways are really that good.

1. Using the Task class or Timer class and have 1 main tick that loops through a list of matches and calls a method on them. (I don't think that this would scale very well if i have thousands of matches.)
2. Having a Task or Timer in each match. (I think that, since i could potentially have, lets say 10000 matches at once, this could have a serious impact on performance.)

I can't think of any other way of doing this, is any of this solutions good? If not, how should i go about this?

Comment: I didn't get your question completely but if you're building game server and you wan to handle millions of user, you should try actor model using http://getakka.net/

Comment: Duplicate: [C# Executing a lot of actions each second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000650/c-sharp-executing-a-lot-of-actions-each-second/) (deleted 1 hour ago by the post author)

Comment: Put the timer in the client and not the server.